# I want to integrate zk in jsp, But I have got Error

Tags: jsp, zk

I am using ZK framework and I want to integrate zk in jsp.I have tried to run following code at server.

Test.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.zkoss.org/jsp/zul" prefix="z" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test of ZUL on JSP</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>1. Header outside z:page</h1>
        <z:page>
            <h2>2. Header in z:page</h2>
            <z:window id="win" title="Test" border="normal">
                <p>3. Content in z:window</p>
                <z:button label="Overlap" onClick="win.doOverlapped()" />
            </z:window>
            <p>
                4. Content in z:page after z:window
            </h2>
        </z:page>
        <p>5. Content after z:page</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have got this Error And I have already added zuljsp.jar in My application Build path

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/zkoss/web/servlet/xel/PageRequestContext
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:491)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:401)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

Please help me out from this error
 thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JAR has got to be into webapp's runtime classpath. Dropping the JAR file(s) in `/WEB-INF/lib` should do it. You don't need to do anything else. You don't need to mess with project's *Build Path* properties in an IDE.

Comment: The class shall be in zweb.jar. Make sure all ZK JAR files are installed. You might refer to http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Installation_Guide/ZK_Background/The_Content_of_ZK_Binary_Distribution#.2Fdist.2Flib